# What is Updater, Dispatcher, context in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm a beginner in python, and I'm trying to make a bot using python-telegram-bot module. But I can't understand what Updater, context and dispatcher is in it. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8):

- `Updater` is a class whose responsibility it is to fetch updates from Telegram, either via `get_updates` or via a webhook
- `Dispatcher` is a class whose responsibility it is to do something with the updates. This is done through the `Handlers` as explained in the docs of [`Dispatcher.add_handler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler). It also manages in-memory dictionaries that can be used to [store bot/chat/user related data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data)
- [`CallbackContext`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html) is a convenience class used in the PTB framework to provide access to commonly used objects into your handler callbacks. For each update one instance of this class is built by the `Dispatcher` and passed to the handler callbacks as second argument.

I highly recommend to read the [tutorial your first bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot), which explains the ptb framework in some detail. Checking out the examples as well as the other wiki pages will help to deepen your understanding of the framework.

Note that `Dispatcher` has been removed in the recent [v20.0a0 pre-release](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotchannel/114), although the new `Application` class resembles `Dispatcher` in many aspects.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`