# 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher' Error

Tags: python, discord, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to make a telegram to discord bot for a select users messages but no matter what I do I run into an error: **AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'**

I cannot find a replacement for dispatcher anywhere. This is the first time im attempting this.

here is my current code:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import *
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import asyncio

telegram_token = ""


discord_token = ""

# Discord Channel ID
discord_channel_id = "112865"


telegram_bot = telegram.Bot(token=telegram_token)


intents = discord.Intents.default()
discord_bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

def telegram_message_handler(update, context):
    message = update.effective_message
    text = message.text
    username = message.from_user.username
    # Send the message to Discord
    discord_message = f"[@{username}]: {text}"
    discord_channel = discord_bot.get_channel(int(discord_channel_id))
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(discord_channel.send(discord_message), discord_bot.loop)


updater = Updater(telegram_token, update_queue=None)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
message_handler = MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, telegram_message_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

@discord_bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Connected to Discord as {discord_bot.user.name}")

@discord_bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == discord_bot.user:
        return
    # Send the message to Telegram
    telegram_chat_id = "dav52"
    await telegram_bot.send_message(chat_id=telegram_chat_id, text=message.content)

# Start the Telegram bot
updater.start_polling()

# Start the Discord bot
discord_bot.run(discord_token)
```

Comment: Why do you think that an Updater instance should have an attribute called dispatcher?

Comment: I just looked an example online. Like I said this is my first time trying. Sorry if its a ridiculous question

Comment: No not a ridiculous question, I just didn't see anything about a dispatcher attribute in the documentation.

According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72522418/3268228), Dispatchers have been removed in the most recent version of this library, so maybe check that.

Here is a tutorial for the current version I think: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot

Comment: It looks like this library has changed substantially in the recently-released version 20, so make sure you're looking at the correct info